# Proof that it's possible to colour all elements in set, that all subsets will be bicolored

Tags: pr.probability, graph-theory, graph-colorings, hypergraph

(*For my easy understanding, let me rewrite the question. The author should feel free to remove my edit or... accept it; **I am leaving the original formulation at the end intact***).

=================

**REFORMULATION**

An ordered pair $(A\ B)$ of subsets of the ring of integers $\mathbf Z$ is called globally ordered if $\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \ a \le b\ $ for every $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Let $k>1$ be an arbitrary natural number. Let $\ S\ $ be a finite family of k-element subsets of $\mathbf Z,\,$ each two of which have a non-empty intersection. **Is it true that** if no two members of $S$ form a globally ordered pair then it's possible to color $\mathbf Z$ in such a way that every member of $S$ is bicolored **?**

================

*PS. I'd like to ask the author to be a bit more detailed and explicit about the definitions related to the coloring.*

================

**THE ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

Assume we have a set of numbers $\{ 1, 2, ..., n \}$ and a set of subsets $\{ M_1, ..., M_s \}$, such that $|M_i| = k$ and $ \forall i,j\ (i\ne j\implies|M_i \cap M_j| = 1)$.

Let's define **2-chain** -- it is two subsets, $M_i, M_j$ with one common element - $x$ and for every element $y \in M_i$ true that $y < x$, and and for every element $z \in M_j$ true that $z > x$. It's increasing **2-chain** and in the same way we could define decreasing **2-chain**.

We make a random permutation of numbers.

Proof that if there is exist such permutation that there is no **2-chains**, that it's possible to colour all numbers in a way that all $M_i$ will be bicolored.

I think that we should use Lovász local lemma, but I can't build proper probability space.

Comment: @bof , of course, for $i \neq j$, sorry for mistake in formulation.

Comment: Accidentally, I omitted the condition about the 1-point intersections. Now I have inserted the non-empty intersections and (I hope) it seems to be fine.

Comment: I feel that the globally ordered together with the later appearance of the non-empty intersection are after all ok. The 1-point follows from these conditions.

Comment: @Włodzimierz Holsztyński yes, thank you for reformulation. I think I'd like to remain both formulation of problems, cause your smoother and more general, and mine, cause it's original problem in form that I have heard it.

Comment: Why can't you just, for each element of $S$ (or each $M_i$), colour the top element red and the bottom element blue? What am I missing?

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński how does 1-point condition follow?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, let $\ (A\ \,B)\ $ be globally ordered, and let $\ {a\ b}\in A\cap B$. Then $\ a\le b\ $ as well as $\ b\le a.\ $ thus $\ a=b$. This means that there cannot be two DIFFERENT common elements of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński but they are NOT globally ordered

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Let $S$ be a family of finite subsets of some linearly ordered set $L.$ Suppose that each member of $S$ has at least two elements, and that no two members of $S$ form a "globally ordered pair". Then we can color every element of $L$ red or blue so that, for each $X\in S,$ the top element of $X$ is red and the bottom element of $X$ is blue.

Comment: This answer is of course utterly trivial, so I suppose I have either misunderstood the question or something has been omitted from the statement.

Comment: You didn't use the assumption about the 1-point intersections, which was extra nice on your part. Of course elements which are not extremal for any member one can color in an arbitrary way.